# efficient QVariant construction from a std::string

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to construct a QVariant from a std::string and have it live inside a std::vector. I'm currently doing:

```
std::string foo = "test";
std::vector<QVariant> variants;
...
variants[0] = QString::fromStdString(foo);
```

This methodology seems to construct a temporary QString, which is then destroyed after the `QVariant(const QString &)` c'tor is called.

Any way to avoid the temp QString?

Comment: `variants.emplace(QString::fromStdString(foo))`, `variants.push_back(QString::fromStdString(foo))`?

Comment: That temporary string's data is actually alive and well - its private data lives on within the variant. The temporary that gets destroyed is a very lightweight shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed want to store `QString`, then due to copy-on-write semantics of Qt, the temporary QString object is irrelevant to performance. Doing text decoding from `std::string` to `QString` is going to dominate, and thanks to COW that data will not get copied anyway (unless modified). If `std::string` is `'\0'`-terminated text, then you can simply use [this QVariant constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariant-14), which might be as optimal as it gets for `QString`:

```
variants.emplace(0, QVariant(stdstr.c_str());
```

---

Alternative solution is to store `std::string` as `QByteArray` instead of `QString`. The one thing you need to decide is, if the `std::string` data needs to be copied or not. If you know the pointer to string data will remain valid for the lifetime of `QByteArray`, you can use [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromRawData):

```
// warning, does not copy string data, so pointer to it must remain valid
variants.emplace(0, QByteArray::fromRawData(stdstr.data(), stdstr.size()));
```

Safer is [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-2), which does copy but no text decoding:

```
variants.emplace(0, QByteArray(stdstr.data(), stdstr.size()));
```

Note that `std::string` does not care about encoding and is 8-bit, so in fact `QByteArray` is its Qt counterpart. `QString` stores Unicode text, UTF-16 internally, so conversion will be always needed, no matter the encoding of `std::string` contents.

Also, you should probably read [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) and [`std::vector::emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) references.

Answer (score 8):

[register](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) `std::string` type, then conversion to `QString` will be obsolete.

```
// in some header file
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE (std::string)

// in main function
qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
```

Comment: This is the correct way to store an std::string in a QVariant, but I think there are several copies involved anyway, so I doubt there will be a significant gain.

Comment: `std::string` also uses copy on write pattern. Also you will avoid costly [conversion](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdString), since even [codec](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromAscii) methods are involved.

Comment: IIRC `std::string` is unlikely to use COW in new versions of the standard due to more stringent thread-safety requirements. OTOH, the point about the codec conversion is definitely relevant, since `QString` works in UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to avoid the temp QString?

Doubtful.

Even if a QString is passed to the QVariant constructor, it makes a copy.

But it does not matter much, since QStrings are implicitely shared, so copying them is an O(1) operation

Although you could store the string as `void*`, but then it is not automatically converted to a string, if you need one.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no copy. Copy only happens on write, and I do not know what you mean by O(1) here. This is not an algorithm, and even if it was, for 'n' elements in the string it is "O(n)".

Comment: I was using the C++ defintion of copy: Calling the copy constructor.